# taging matched keyword in apache flume

Tags: hadoop, twitter, twitter4j, flume

im using one of the many guides to stream data from Twitters streaming API into HDFS, via flume. I need to append the matched keyword somewhere in the data flow so I can see which keyword generated which tweet. Can anyone recommend a method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Interceptor](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-interceptors). Flume allows you to inspect the event and add additional data either as header or augment existing event.